# Maven Svn SCM delete tag

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to implement a maven plugin and faced some problem with scm. The plugin needs to delete a tag, but I could not find a way to do it. 
Does anybody have experience with this API?

Comment: Why do you need to delete a tag?

Comment: Then you should vote for the bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-229, if it's not yet done ! Exactly your problem.

Comment: And this problem is also reported in the release plugin documenation. See [Rollback a Release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/rollback-release.html)

Answer (score 2):

There does not exist such a possibility to delete a tag via the SCM API in Maven. If this would be possible the release:rollback would have already implemented such a thing. On the other hand some SCM systems don't allow deleting of tags.
It might be an option to implement the delteting of the tag via other API's (I assume you are using SVN?) you could use SVNKit directly in your plugin. The contents of the release.properties gives you the name of the tag which can be deleted in case of a failure.

Comment: Actually my problem is the release plugin. It leaves the project in an unstable state when it fails, and I wanted to implement the delete so that it could clean up after failure. I also noticed that the rollback target is not implemented in the release plugin, but it shouldn't mean that it cannot be implemented.

Comment: Hm..unstable state...Only the tag which has to be removed manually.The rollback target doesn't delete the tag yes, but the other things will be undone. What do you mean by not "implemented"?